# Problem querying in facebook app

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook application at http://apps.facebook.com/nitz_dola_apps/ . And yes this is my first facebook app.Now my question is to get list of my friends I need to click on the link http://www.graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_toke=.Although I am getting the response,how I will query those data ? Is there any way so that I can get the data without clicking the link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the file_get_contents method. Like this

```
  $contents = json_decode(file_get_contents(http://www.graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_toke=xyz));
```

$contents contains the array of your friend names and ids.